# final-form: reset single field

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

For example I have this simple field. How can I reset only this field by clicking the button

```
<Field name="myField">
  {props => (
    <div>
      <input {...props.input} />
      <button onClick={()=> {
       // Reset function
      }>
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resetFieldState](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#resetfieldstate) or [change](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#change) or borth methods. Also you can use [getFieldState](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#getfieldstate) to get field **initial** value for **change**.

More complex way, is to create custom mutator for reseting field.